# How to Convert a temporarily class to json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have a class and easy to convert to json

But sometimes I want add some properties to the json

I should create another class and convert to json ?

I have a class

```
    class Person{
string name{get;set;}
string age{get;set;}
}
```

and If I want to add a property like sex
I have to create a class that has the name,age and sex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Anonymous Types for the purpose. For example,

```
var data = new {Name="abc",Gender="male"};
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Output

```
{"Name":"abc","Gender":"male"}
```

You can deserialize the json to Anonymous Type using [DeserializeAnonymousType](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm)

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(result, new{Name="",Gender=""});
```